# $\Bbb R^2$ with a scaled metric not complete

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Show that the Riemannian manifold $\Bbb R^2$ equipped with a scaled version of the flat Euclidean metric $g^E$ given by $g_{(x,y)} = e^yg^E_{(x,y)}$ is not a complete Riemannian manifold.

It is sufficient to prove that this manifold is not complete as a metric space, but I don't see what is the issue. At every point $(x,0)$ in the $x$-axis the metric $g$ is the same as the Euclidean metric, and when we start to go above the $x$-axis to points $(x,y)$ the metric is a scaled version of the standard Euclidean metric so the length's of the vectors become longer.

Similarly if we go below the $x$-axis to points $(x,-y)$ the  vectors become shorter due to $e^{-y}$ decreasing them.

I now need to find a Cauchy sequence in this space with the property that it does not converge. I can't think of how I can utilize this scaling factor to generate a Cauchy sequence that wouldn't converge. I have the intuition that this scaling factor might let me be able to consider sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ that would not be Cauchy in the standard flat Euclidean space, but I don't know how to come up with one. Could someone give me a hint on what can we do with this scaled metric?

Comment: Consider $x_n = (0,-n)$. What is $d(x_n,x_{n+1})$?

Comment: $d((0,-n), (0,-{n+1})) = e^{?}\sqrt{(n-(-(n+1))^2} = e^{?}\sqrt{(2n+1)^2}=e^?(2n+1)$. Is it $-n$ or $-(n+1)$ that should be the exponent? @Didier

Comment: That is not how you compute distances in Riemannian geometry

Comment: I know that we should take the infimum of admissible paths, but is it not the same as this in Euclidean space? @Didier

Comment: You have to compute $\int_0^1 |\gamma'|_g dt$ for some $\gamma$ joining the said points to obtain an upper bound on the distance.

Comment: Can you take $\gamma(t) = (1-t)(0,-n) + t(0,-(n+1))$? @Didier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N} = \{(0,-n)\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$.
The path
$$\gamma(t) = (1-t)x_n + tx_m = (0,-n + t(n-m)),$$
for $t\in [0,1]$ and $m > n$, joins $x_n$ to $x_m$.
It satisfies $\gamma'(t) = (0,n-m)$.
Hence, for $m > n$,
\begin{align}
d(x_n,x_m)
&\leqslant \ell(\gamma) \\
&= \int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)|_g \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))}\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^1 e^{-\frac{n + t(m-n)}{2}}(m-n) \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e^{-\frac{n}{2}}(m-n)\int_0^1 e^{-t\frac{m-n}{2}} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e^{-\frac{n}{2}}(m-n)\frac{2}{m-n}\left(1-e^{-\frac{m-n}{2}}\right) \\
&= 2(e^{-\frac{n}{2}}-e^{-\frac{m}{2}}).
\end{align}
Can you go on from there?

Comment: So your calculation shows that $x_n$ is Cauchy as $2(e^{-\frac{n}{2}}-e^{-\frac{m}{2}}) \to 0$, but $x_n$ doesn't converge since $-n$ grows without a bound. May I still ask how did you figure out $(0,-n)$ would work? @didier

Comment: Essentially, yes, but you need to be more precise that "grows without a bound". You have to show that whatever $x\in \Bbb R^2$, you don't have $d(x,x_n) \to 0$. // Here is the idea: the $e^y$ factor "contracts" the metric as $y \to -\infty$, so that the distance between evenly "euclideanly-spaced" pairs of points  goes to zero for the distance induced by $g$ in this direction.

Comment: Note that a Cauchy sequence for $g$ that is not Cauchy for the euclidean metric *must* "go to infinity": if not, it will be trapped in a compact set, say $[-K,K]^2$, and the two metrics are bi-Lipschitz on this compact with $e^{-K/2}d_{\mathrm{eucl}} \leqslant d_g \leqslant e^{K/2}d_{\mathrm{eucl}}$. In other words, they have the same Cauchy sequences when restricted to compacts.